# re-downloading a single in-app purchase from hosted content

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I have an iOS app that implements in app purchases.
However i have a use-case where a user needs to re-download the content for a single in app purchase that has previously been purchased.

I cant use restoreCompletedTransactions because it will restore all transactions. in this case i want to just re-download a single transactions content based on a product identifier without making the user go through the "traumatic" buy again and you wont be charged process.

anyone know how to do?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can initiate the restore without the user being prompted for a password, but you can pick out the one product you want to download so:

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(nonnull SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(nonnull NSArray<SKPaymentTransaction *> *)transactions {
    for(SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions){
        switch(transaction.transactionState){
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
            {
                if ([transaction.payment.productIdentifier isEqualToString:MY_PRODUCT_ID])
                {
                    [queue startDownloads:transaction.downloads];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```